# JTable add rows bottom up - rows added one after the other should appear at the bottom of the last one but all should be bottom aligned

Tags: java, swing

I have a JTable in Java swing which needs to be bottom aligned.

As in normal tables when a row is added to the table it is placed on top, when the next row is added it is added under it and so on.

What I would like to do is place the new row at the bottom of the table. When a new row is added I would like the new row to be placed right at the bottom and the previous row to move up. This way the rows appear to move upward. 
Basically the rows should stick to the bottom.

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: Do you mean you want to have empty space between your table header and top row if it's not pushed all the way to the top? If so, @Steve Jackson's answer won't cut it and you'll need to either use custom table UI or use a second, empty table to display he header, and use a layout manager to keep the data table at bottom.

Comment: Yep, I misread the question entirely.  Deleted my answer.

Comment: Yes, meant that all row in the table frame should stick to the bottom. Isn't there a simple way to tell the rows 'bottom align' to table frame?

Comment: please indicate if you want empty space between table header and first row, or empty rows are ok. If the latter, use @tulskiy's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3881317/jtable-add-rows-bottom-up-rows-added-one-after-the-other-should-appear-at-the-b/3882252#3882252), which I think is the same as @Steve Jackson's deleted one :)

Comment: I really would like empty space between the table header and the first row. (Just like in normal tables there is empty space between the last row and table bottom border). But if that is not possible I will go with @tulskiy's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the decorator pattern. Assuming a class named TableModelDecorator which decorates a TableModel you can implement:

```
public class TableEmptyReverseRowsModel extends TableModelDecorator {

private int minimumRows;

public TableEmptyReverseRowsModel(final TableModel realModel, 
                            final int minimumRows) {
    super(realModel);

    this.minimumRows = minimumRows;
}

public int getRowCount() {
    int realCount = model.getRowCount();        
    return realCount < minimumRows ? minimumRows : realCount;
}


public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    int diff = minimumRows - model.getRowCount();

    if (diff > 0) {
        if (rowIndex < diff) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return model.isCellEditable(rowIndex - diff, columnIndex);
        }
    } else {
        return model.isCellEditable(rowIndex, columnIndex);
    }
}

public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    int diff = minimumRows - model.getRowCount();

    if (diff > 0) {
        if (rowIndex < diff) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return model.getValueAt(rowIndex - diff, columnIndex);
        }
    } else {
        return model.getValueAt(rowIndex, columnIndex);
    }
}

public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    int diff = minimumRows - model.getRowCount();

    if (diff > 0) {
        if (rowIndex < diff) {

        } else {
            super.setValueAt(aValue, rowIndex - diff, columnIndex);
        }
    } else {
        super.setValueAt(aValue, rowIndex, columnIndex);
    }
}

}
```

Be aware of the cell renderer that must handle the null value ;)

See ya!

Answer (score 0):

If @Geoffrey Zheng's assumption is correct, then you can create a table with `n` empty rows, (eg. a Vector of `n` `null`'s), and then replace elements in the order you need.

Answer (score 0):

The code below shows one way to do this with a JList. It will be a little more complicate for a JTable since you will need a second JPanel with a BorderLayout. You would add the table header to the North and the main panel to the Center. Then this panel would be added to the viewport or the scrollpane.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

public class ListBottom2 extends JFrame
{
    JList list;
    JTextField textField;

    public ListBottom2()
    {
        DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
        model.addElement("First");
        list = new JList(model);
        list.setVisibleRowCount(5);

        JPanel box = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() );
        box.setBackground( list.getBackground() );
        box.add(list, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( box );
        scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 100));
        add( scrollPane );

        textField = new JTextField("Use Enter to Add");
        getContentPane().add(textField, BorderLayout.NORTH );
        textField.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                JTextField textField = (JTextField)e.getSource();
                DefaultListModel model = (DefaultListModel)list.getModel();
                model.addElement( textField.getText() );
                int size = model.getSize() - 1;
                list.scrollRectToVisible( list.getCellBounds(size, size) );
                textField.setText("");
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ListBottom2 frame = new ListBottom2();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }
}
```